# Is there a way to make a job with a precompiled sql and run it multiple times via java api (bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to make a job with a precompiled sql and run it multiple times via java api (bigquery)?

I know i can use jobs, but there is no way to fast re-run a job.

As google states:

There is no single-call method to re-run a job; if you want to re-run a specific job:

Call jobs.get to retrieve the resource for the job to re-run,
Remove the id, jobId, status, and statistics field. Change any other fields as necessary.
Call jobs.insert with the modified resource to start the new job.

How can i do this, with what function?:
Remove the id, jobId, status, and statistics field. Change any other fields as necessary.

If i manage to this, to reset the jobconfiguration, will it use the nested sql statement as precompiled? Im curious

Thanks in advance:

Attila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have a concept of precompiled SQL. Generally, the analysis of the SQL statement only accounts for a very small proportion of the query time, so pre-compiling it wouldn't provide much benefit.

Re-running the job (by sending the same jobconfiguration) should work, however.